# determine the gcd of $n^3+3n^2-5 $ and $ n+2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Hello I have to determine the gcd of $n^3+3n^2-5 $ and $ n+2$, but I can’t do it because I know we have to eliminate the $n$. I tried to eliminate $n^3 $ but I’m stuck for the rest.

Comment: You are allowed to multiply either one by an expression including $n$, then subtract.  That should allow you to clear the $n^3$ if you choose the expression well.

Comment: $$n^3+3n^2-5-n^2(n+2)=n^2-5$$

Comment: do you know that $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b \pm k)$ where $k \in Z$

Comment: Follows immediately from the Euclidean Algorithm or Remainder Theorem as explained in the linked dupes, i.e. $\,\gcd(f(n),n+2) = \gcd(f(-2),n+2)\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$n^3 + 3n^2 - 5 - n^2 (n+2) = n^2 - 5$$
and
$$n^2 - 5 - n(n+2) = -2n-5$$
Why did I do this? $\gcd(f(x),g(x)) = \gcd(f(x) - \lambda g(x), g(x))$ where $\lambda$ is an integer. So, keeping the above two equations in mind we have
$$\gcd(n^3 + 3n^2 - 5, n+2) = \gcd(-2n-5, n+2) = 1$$
i.e. the two are co-prime (the greatest common divisor is $1$).

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $n^3+3n^2-5=(n+2)^3-3(n+2)^2-1$.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be their gcd. Then $$n^3 +3n^2 -5 = ga \\ n+2 = gb $$ Subtract the first from the cube of the second: $$3n^2 +12n +13 = g^3b^3 -ga $$ Subtract from this thrice the square of the second equation: $$1 = g^3b^3 -ga-3g^2b^2 = g(g^2 b^3 -a-3gb^2)$$ This implies $$g=1$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque Again, I didn’t know this was a dupe.

Comment: Do you know how to search for dupes, e.g. using https://approach0.xyz/search/ ?

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, but it’s kind of inconvenient to do this for every question I answer.